# convert Bitmap to Byte array without compress method in android

Tags: android, arrays, bitmap

I want to upload an image to my website via my android app so for that i want to convert my image to Byte[].

i have used the following code but not work for me..

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG,0, bos);
    byte[] data=bos.toByteArray();
```

So please share with me any other way to convert an Image to Byte[]..

Comment: please share some code what you have done

Comment: For what reason you need to convert and what you have already tried?

Comment: I have ans for this in iphone... Sorry not for Android...

Comment: Do you have a feed-back on the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Use `ByteBuffer`:

```
 array = new byte[w*h*4];
 Buffer dst = ByteBuffer.wrap(array);
 bmp.copyPixelsToBuffer(dst);
```

and use array the way you want...